# Proving null space of adjoint operator is equal to the dense range

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I'm close to being done with a proof, but I'm not sure whether it's correct and there are a few things I'm unsure about. I'll start off by stating the theorem I'm trying to prove:

$\textit{For a bounded linear operator we have}$

$$A(X)^{\perp}=N(A^{*})\textit{ and }N(A^{*})^{\perp}=\overline{A(X)}$$

Here $A(X)$ means the range of a Hilbert space $X$, $N(A^{*})$ means the null space of the adjoint operator $A^{*}$.

I've proven the first part of the statement completely and with no issues, but it's the second one that's bothering me. Here is the outline of my proof so far:

$\textit{Proof that }N(A^{*})=\overline{A(X)}$.

Every topological space is a dense subset of itself, i.e. $\overline{A(X)}\subset(A(X)^{\perp})^{\perp}$, where $(A(X)^{\perp})^{\perp}=A(X)$. Now fix some $\varphi\in (A(X)^{\perp})^{\perp}$.

Consider now the orthogonal projection operator $P:Y\rightarrow\overline{A(X)}$. Since $P\varphi\in\overline{A(X)}\subset (A(X)^{\perp})^{\perp}$ that implies $P\varphi\in (A(X)^{\perp})^{\perp}$ From here we can see that $P\varphi-\varphi\perp A(X)^{\perp}$. Now, consider writing $\varphi$ as $\varphi=\varphi_1+\varphi_2$, where $\varphi_1\in (A(X)^{\perp})^{\perp}$ and $\varphi_2\in A(X)^{\perp}$. This means that $P\varphi=\varphi_1$ and $P\varphi-\varphi=-\varphi_2\in A(X)^{\perp}$, hence $P\varphi-\varphi\perp A(X)$.

Since $P\varphi-\varphi\perp A(X)$ and $P\varphi-\varphi\perp A(X)^{\perp}$, that must mean that $\varphi=P\varphi\in\overline{A(X)}$ and thus we have $\overline{A(X)}=(A(X)^{\perp})^{\perp}$, which by using the first part of the theorem yields $\overline{A(X)}=N(A^{*})^{\perp}$

Please let me know if there's something that isn't quite right or if there's another way you would do it! Also, I feel like I'm lacking an argument for why $P\varphi=\varphi$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Proof that $N(A^*)^\perp = \overline{R(A)}$:
Let $x = Az$ for some $z \in X$ and let $y \in N(A^*)$.
$$\langle y,x \rangle = \langle y, Az \rangle = \langle A^*y,z\rangle = 0.$$
Therefore $x \in N(A^*)^\perp$ and, as $N(A^*)^\perp$ is closed, $\overline{R(A)} \subset N(A^*)^\perp$. 
Let $x \in N(A^*)^\perp$. Assume $x \notin \overline{R(A)}$. By the Hahn Banach theorem there exists a $y \in X$ with $\langle y,x \rangle \neq 0$ but $\langle y, \cdot \rangle \vert_{\overline{R(A)}} = 0$. This is a contradiction as $y \in N(A^*)$ but $\langle y,x \rangle \neq 0$.

The first one follows immediately from the second one:
$$N(A^*) = (N(A^*)^\perp)^\perp = \overline{R(A)}^\perp.$$

Comment: I'm not sure why $\langle y,\cdot\rangle|_{\overline{R(A)}}=0$

Comment: $R(A)$ is a closed subspace of $X$. The existence of such a functional is a consequence of the Hahn Banach theorem. Also check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn%E2%80%93Banach_theorem#Important_consequences.